# is this formula provable in predicate logic? ⊢ (∀x)(∀y)(f(x1) = y1 → ((∀z)g(z) = f(x1) ≡ (∀z)g(z) = y1))

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, provability

"Can you prove ⊢ (∀x)(∀y)(f(x1) = y1 → ((∀z)g(z) = f(x1) ≡ (∀z)g(z) = y1)) in predicate logic? explain."

I'm saying no, but I'm not sure why. Is it because it's not a tautology? and how would Godel's incompleteness theorems come to play here?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: I think Godel's theorems are about formal systems representing basic arithmetic. Not the system of predicate logic.

Comment: oh okay, so how would we know if this is or isn't provable?

Comment: What are x1 and y1 in the statement? The quantifiers are over x, y and z so it seems odd.

Comment: Godel's completeness theorem states that all valid first order formulas are provable. Godel's incompleteness theorems say there are undecidable statements in any system powerful enough to represent arithmetic, and you can do that in first order predicate logic. This statement isn't powerful enough for it to apply however. Only monadic functions and an equality predicate suggest it's decidable.

Comment: @coffeemath http://math.yorku.ca/~brettler/1090_w14/FinalNatasha1090.pdf

the question comes from page 4 question 3c on that link. I'm not sure why the professor wrote x1 and y1 instead of just x and y

Comment: It is easily provable with *Natural Deduction* rules for *identity* : (=symm) : $s=t⊢t=s$ and (=trans) : $s=t,t=r⊢s=r$.

Answer (score 0):

In first order logic, there are validities in addition to tautologies. These statements are statements that are true in every possible interpretation, and just not being a tautology isn't enough to tell you if it's a valid statement or not. Gödel's incompleteness theorems suggest that for every system that's powerful enough to represent arithmetic, there are statements that are undecidable... that is the truth value might be true in a particular model but not be a theorem of the formal system, but that doesn't say that validity is undecidable directly.

Church's theorem does however. That's the answer to the *Entscheidungsproblem*, the question on whether there's an algorithm to decide the validity of a first order statement. Church answered this in the negative for statements that are sufficiently complex.

I can't say for sure in your particular statement, since the statement looks a bit ambiguous, with quantifiers not matching any variables, and syntactic identity symbol being used where I think biconditional is meant. However if I take your statement to be this one in prenex normal form:

$\forall$x$\forall$y$\forall$z$\forall$u : ((f(x) = y) $\implies$ (g(z) = f(x)) $\iff$ (g(u) = y))

Then we can say some things about it. First, it *is* decidable since the only dyadic predicate is equality. This means we can determine whether it's a valid statement though several ways. We can negate the statement and use resolution. If we come up with the empty clause, it's a contradiction and hence it's *unsatisfiable*. The negation of an unsatisfiable statement is a valid statement. If you run out of rules, you've saturated the search and proven it satisfiable.

But satisfiable doesn't mean valid. A formula can be satisfiable and it's negation can be satisfiable as well, and what that means is there are models for each instance. This opens another way to find out if the statement is provable or not: finite model generation. I think that since the statement has only equality and monadic functions that if there's a model of it the model is finite so we can generate interpretations of the statement to see if it applies. If there's a finite model for the statement and the negation of the statement, the statement is unprovable also.

You can prove, through saturation of resolution or finite model generation that the statement isn't logically valid. It is satisfiable though.

Comment: thank you for your answer. heres the link to the question http://math.yorku.ca/~brettler/1090_w14/FinalNatasha1090.pdf, it is question 3c on the 4th page, so you can see I have not miscommunicated the question.

i guess resolution would be the way to go, don't know why I didn't think of that. But again, thank you. I will try using resolution and see if I can come up with a proof for this formula